# How do I stop numbers from being converted to Scientific Notation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

In my worksheet I do something like

```
 sheet.add_row [c.date,c.specialtext], style: header
```

where c.specialtext can be a really long int or some text.  When ever it is an int the number is always converted to scientific notation.  Is there a style I can add that will prevent this from happening using the axlsx gem?

Comment: Try add `num_fmt: 1` on your `header` style

Comment: Hey I tried what you said and it does stop the scientific notation, but it starts rounding the number if it is really long.  When I have: 234817234891234912471298347243 the excel sheet shows: 234817234891235000000000000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat it like a string:

```
sheet.add_row [c.date,c.specialtext], style: header, types: [:string]
```